# page count won´t add +1 to count field

Tags: php, mysql

I´ve been trying to make "most popular article" script

retrieve the most popular is no problem.... but I have tried every "add count+" methods
but the count field in my mysql always shows 0

This is my script

```
$add = "1";

$counter=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsid = '".$newsid."'");

while ($ntcounter=mysql_fetch_array($counter)) {    
    mysql_query("UPDATE news SET count = '".$ntcounter[count]+$add."' WHERE newsid = '".$newsid."'")
}
```

I´m starting to think if the database is not updateable

Is there something I´m missing here?

Comment: try `.($ntcounter[count]+$add).`

Comment: Turn on `error_reprting` - what is `$ntcounter[count]` `count` doing in this case?

Comment: I really don´t know - just copy/pasted from some tutorial

Maybe this would work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one go:

```
UPDATE news SET `count` = `count`+1 WHERE newsid = '".$newsid."'
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
<?php 
//TURN ON ERROR REPORTING!!!
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Type cast the variable to an integer, despite where its set 
(int)$newsid=1;
//or
(int)$newsid=$_GET['id'];
//$newsid="1"; is setting 1 as a string

mysql_query("UPDATE news SET `count` = `count`+1 WHERE newsid=".$newsid);
?>
```

Note if your not checking or casting type. always remember to use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Phew, was starting to pull my hair out lol ;p. glad you sorted it, suggest you look up some more tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing it like that at all. MySQL has built-in functionality for increasing values, you can just do:

```
UPDATE news SET count = count+1 WHERE newsid = '$newsid'
```

Comment: exactly the one should be working....

count field is INT but still shows 0

Could it be some adjustment in mysql that are blocking UPDATE?

Comment: If you have insufficient privileges, you'd get a MySQL error. How have you tested it? Have you checked to make sure that `$newsid` contains what you think it does?

Comment: I´m not too good at this... trying if I see something in information scema... I´ve had a huge problem with basic editNews.php - wont update... so I suppose it has something to do with privileges

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything. Have you attempted to execute a query such as `UPDATE news SET count = count+1 WHERE newsid = '1'` manually though the command line or with a tool such as phpMyAdmin?

Comment: not sure how that's done :/ .... but I´m 100% sure this script is the one should works.. but there just something tiny missing

Comment: If you set error reporting on it will spit out errors, (php 101) but I believe your problem is that your trying to pass a string into an INT field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your `$add` should be an integer.

```
$add = 1;
```